# Creating a click count on link in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a code that counts the click on the link which is on my website and adds 1 to the `LINKCOUNT` row in the mysql database, but im having trouble over coding.

This is my code when I click the LINK on my website:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "123", "123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("123") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, sitename FROM links WHERE siteurl = \"www\"");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (linkcount) VALUES  $row['linkcount']");
$count = 0;
```

Not sure if that is right way of doing it, any ideas what the code will be?

EDIT

I can now add 1 to the LINKCOUNT row but every link i click adds to the same row, i need each link to have seperate row and click count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE `links` SET `linkcount` = `linkcount` + 1 WHERE `siteurl` = 'www'
```

And about your code: your query doesn't select the `linkcount` column, so `$row['linkcount']` is always null.

EDIT:

If your table doesn't contain rows for every link you want to track, you should use that kind of code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `links` SET `linkcount` = `linkcount` + 1 WHERE `siteurl` = 'SITE_URL'");
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `links` (`sitename`, `siteurl`, `linkcounter`) VALUES ('SITE_NAME', 'SITE_URL', 1)");
```

You have to insert proper SITE_NAME and SITE_URL

Comment: thank you, should I be adding the line of your code or replace one of the line from my code with the UPDATE?

Comment: If you don't need the current counter on php-side that update statement will be enough.

Comment: I have removed the last 2 lines from my code and replaced with your code but it doesnt add 1 to the LINKCOUNT column in my database

Comment: there was but i have deleted that row and still does not work

Comment: This row NEEDS to be there - that query doesn't add new row, it updates the existing one.

Comment: You can also make use of UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY for this kind of feature.

Comment: i am sorry yes i have "id" "siteurl" "sitename" and "linkcount" in my LINKS table

Comment: does my table have to be empty??? or will it add the link in the database? I am not sure or do i have to enter all the links  in the database

Comment: Thank you, it now adds a link count to 1 but it displays "SITE_NAME" and "SITE_URL" in sitename and siteurl rows rather then showing the actual name and the url, is this possible?

Comment: SITE_NAME and SITE_URL are just a placeholders which should be replaced with your proper name/url.

Comment: but i will have about 5-6 links, do i have to create a database of links and then put them in a variable and then write them instead of SINE_NAME and SITE_URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can hash the links with `md5`. Use the md5sum of the link as the primary key and check for the link in the table. If it is already present then do an update or else insert the md5sum to the table with the `linkcount = 0`.

Follow the following steps :

- Get the link's md5sum
- Fire a select query on the table to check for that md5sum
- If there are more than 0 rows returned the fire an Update query like

`UPDATE links SET linkcount = linkcount + 1 WHERE md5sum = "md5sum"`

- Else insert a new row into the table with `linkcount = 1`